# Creating a cython file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, pyinstaller

I have recently switched to a windows OS but file is not being found with cython.  The file seems correct.

I run:

```
CD C:\Users\Django\example-of-cython-pyinstaller-and-subzero\1 ACTUAL PROJECT
`python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and get `No such file or directory`
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\Django\ee\123>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'myapp.cython_module' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\include -IC:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" /Tcmyapp/cython_module.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\myapp/cython_module.obj
cython_module.c
c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'myapp/cython_module.c': No such file or directory
```

C:\Users\Django\example-of-cython-pyinstaller-and-subzero\1 ACTUAL PROJECT\myapp

setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages, Extension
from distutils.core import setup


from distutils.core import setup

from setuptools import find_packages, Extension

from setuptools import setup, Extension
setup(
    name='myapp',
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('myapp.cython_module', ['myapp/cython_module.pyx'])
    ],
)
```

[enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9i1h.png)

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? To freeze with Pyinstaller an application with a Cython module?

Comment: @gmas80 Correct.  This has been working but new os change and no go.

Comment: @gmas80 At a guess maybe username change.  It works with already made C files.  The point here is to create c files from pyx though so not too helpful.

Comment: @gmas80 Okay I'm silly.  I totally forgot to install Cython on install.  .  Anyway that did it for me.  The message was a bit misleading.

Comment: There is not call to `cythonize` the pyx

Comment: @gmas80 Looks pretty cythonised to me: https://ibb.co/jwhdAG